Is there a way to bring in interactive content to website from another website without using an iFrame?
I have a website ( www.abc.com ) that needs to display interactive content from another website (say www.def.com ). I know this can be done with iframe.
Is there another method ?
EXAMPLE - def.com is a flight booking "widget" so I have to bring in fully functional website, with JavaScript etc. User should be able to interact with def.com, and book flights, while the browser is still on abc.com



Scripts, generally. 2) web components.


Why wouldn't you want to use an iframe? Can you elaborate on your specific needs?

@Brad I believe there is no other way except iFrame, I am hoping for a confirmation that nothing has changed in the last 6 years (this is how long I was not following front-end tech) :)

@GregBala Frankly, this question doesn't make any sense.  There has always been other ways by including scripts from other sites.  Go back 25 years or so and every major website on the planet had some "widget" you could install.  Maybe only two thirds of them embedded an iframe for that, and the rest would inject content in other ways.

@Brad I am not asking for a script/ widget injection. I am looking for a way, to bring in a display a different website, inside my website. and both website should function perfectly fine including any further post and get they made, they should happen independently as if in iFrame
